# Oracle - Parent - child + fill mising hierarchy levels

Tags: oracle

I have created my fiddle example here: [FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=704a3d1246c5e93175ca5e2ded8c1dd8)
Here is also athe code from the fiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE T1(ID INT, CODE INT, CODE_NAME VARCHAR(100), PARENT_ID INT);

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(100,1,'LEVEL 1', NULL);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(110,11,'LEVEL 2', 100);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(120,111,'LEVEL 3', 110);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(125,112,'LEVEL 3', 110);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(130,1111,'LEVEL 4', 120);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(200,2,'LEVEL 1', NULL);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(210,21,'LEVEL 2', 200);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(300,3,'LEVEL 1', NULL);
```

I have trouble finding the soultuin how to get from that table this result:

```
|  CODE  |  CODE NAME | CODE 1 |CODE NAME 1| CODE 2 | CODE NAME 2| CODE 3 | CODE NAME 3 |
+--------+------------+--------+-----------+--------+------------+--------+-------------+
|   1    |  LEVEL 1   |   11   |  LEVEL 2  |  111   | LEVEL 3    |  1111  |    LEVEL 4  |
|   1    |  LEVEL 1   |   11   |  LEVEL 2  |  112   | LEVEL 3    |   112  |    LEVEL 3  |   
|   2    |  LEVEL 1   |   21   |  LEVEL 2  |   21   | LEVEL 2    |    21  |    LEVEL 2  |
|   3    |  LEVEL 1   |   3    |  LEVEL 1  |    3   | LEVEL 1    |     3  |    LEVEL 1  |
```

I have tried something with `connect by` but that is not what I need(I think)...
The max I will ever have is 4 levels and if there are only two levels in the data then the 3rd and the 4th level should be filled wiht the values of the last existing value. The same rule is valid if there are 3 levels or 1 level.

Comment: You should realy clarify if you want to see one record for each root key or for each *leave* key - your example matches both options...

Comment: Hello @MarmiteBomber I hope my new records in my question and new records in my desired result clear that part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive sub-query:

```sql
WITH hierarchy (
  code,  code_name,
  code1, code_name1,
  code2, code_name2,
  code3, code_name3,
  id, depth
) AS (
  SELECT code,
         code_name,
         CAST(NULL AS INT),
         CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(100)),
         CAST(NULL AS INT),
         CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(100)),
         CAST(NULL AS INT),
         CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(100)),
         id,
         1
  FROM   t1
  WHERE  parent_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
  SELECT h.code,
         h.code_name,
         CASE depth WHEN 1 THEN COALESCE(t1.code, h.code) ELSE h.code1 END,
         CASE depth WHEN 1 THEN COALESCE(t1.code_name, h.code_name) ELSE h.code_name1 END,
         CASE depth WHEN 2 THEN COALESCE(t1.code, h.code1) ELSE h.code2 END,
         CASE depth WHEN 2 THEN COALESCE(t1.code_name, h.code_name1) ELSE h.code_name2 END,
         CASE depth WHEN 3 THEN COALESCE(t1.code, h.code2) ELSE h.code3 END,
         CASE depth WHEN 3 THEN COALESCE(t1.code_name, h.code_name2) ELSE h.code_name3 END,
         t1.id,
         h.depth + 1
  FROM   hierarchy h
         LEFT OUTER JOIN t1
         ON (h.id = t1.parent_id)
  WHERE  depth < 4
)
CYCLE code, depth SET is_cycle TO 1 DEFAULT 0
SELECT code,  code_name,
       code1, code_name1,
       code2, code_name2,
       code3, code_name3
FROM   hierarchy
WHERE  depth = 4;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE T1(ID, CODE, CODE_NAME, PARENT_ID) AS
SELECT 100, 1,    'LEVEL 1',  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 110, 11,   'LEVEL 2',  100  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 120, 111,  'LEVEL 3',  110  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 130, 1111, 'LEVEL 4',  120  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 2,    'LEVEL 1',  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 210, 21,   'LEVEL 2a', 200  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 220, 22,   'LEVEL 2b', 200  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 230, 221,  'LEVEL 3',  220  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 300, 3,    'LEVEL 1',  NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CODE | CODE_NAME | CODE1 | CODE_NAME1 | CODE2 | CODE_NAME2 | CODE3 | CODE_NAME3 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | LEVEL 1 | 11 | LEVEL 2 | 111 | LEVEL 3 | 1111 | LEVEL 4 |
> | 3 | LEVEL 1 | 3 | LEVEL 1 | 3 | LEVEL 1 | 3 | LEVEL 1 |
> | 2 | LEVEL 1 | 21 | LEVEL 2a | 21 | LEVEL 2a | 21 | LEVEL 2a |
> | 2 | LEVEL 1 | 22 | LEVEL 2b | 221 | LEVEL 3 | 221 | LEVEL 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b6005a1e03ad5e3d2fcd3d55fea1fb20)*

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. The solution looks to work nicely except the second part of my question where I ask to fill missing levels. I am not sure if that is clear from my question... I will try to figure how to resolve that.

Comment: @VBoka Updated to use `COALESCE` to fill the missing levels.

Answer (score 1):

For sample data you posted:

```
SQL> select * from t1;

        ID       CODE CODE_NAME   PARENT_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       100          1 LEVEL 1
       110         11 LEVEL 2           100
       120        111 LEVEL 3           110
       130       1111 LEVEL 4           120
       200          2 LEVEL 1
       210         21 LEVEL 2           200

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

an *ugly* (and who-knows-how-performant) query that, though, returns desired result is

```
with temp as
  (select id, code, code_name, parent_id, level lvl,
      row_number() over (partition by level order by id) rn
   from t1
   start with parent_id is null
   connect by prior id = parent_id
  ),
a as
  (select * from temp where lvl = 1),
b as
  (select * from temp where lvl = 2),
c as
  (select * from temp where lvl = 3),
d as
  (select * from temp where lvl = 4)  
select 
           a.code                          code1,          a.code_name                                         code_name1,
  coalesce(b.code, a.code)                 code2, coalesce(b.code_name, a.code_name)                           code_name2,
  coalesce(c.code, b.code, a.code)         code3, coalesce(c.code_name, b.code_name, a.code_name)              code_name3,
  coalesce(d.code, c.code, b.code, a.code) code4, coalesce(d.code_name, c.code_name, b.code_name, a.code_name) code_name4
from a join b on b.rn = a.rn
       left join c on c.rn = b.rn
       left join d on d.rn = c.rn;
```

which results in

```
     CODE1 CODE_NAME1      CODE2 CODE_NAME2      CODE3 CODE_NAME3      CODE4 CODE_NAME4
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 LEVEL 1            11 LEVEL 2           111 LEVEL 3          1111 LEVEL 4
         2 LEVEL 1            21 LEVEL 2            21 LEVEL 2            21 LEVEL 2
```

What does it do?

- `temp` CTE creates a *hierarchy*; additionally, `row_number` function numbers each row within the same level
- `a, b, c, d` CTEs extract values belonging to their own level value (you said there can be up to 4 levels)
- finally, `coalesce` on column names along with `outer join` do the job

Comment: First of all: THANK YOU. Second: when I enter only first level with null value in parent_id column then it does not show the third record: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=aa731380cb4c1c8b2760d3b4719b3ea7 I should have entered that example at the begining...  I will try to find out why.

Comment: This does not work if you have multiple items at a deeper level as the `ROW_NUMBER` values will not match. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ede796416d678f8d1d3dd14067f3882a)

Answer (score 1):

From your example I assume you want to see *one row per root key* as your example is not realy a *tree* but a *bamboo*

If so this is a trivial `PIVOT` query - unfortunately limited to some level deep (here example for your 4 levels)

```
with p (ROOT_CODE, CODE, CODE_NAME, ID, PARENT_ID, LVL) as (
select CODE, CODE, CODE_NAME, ID, PARENT_ID, 1 LVL from t1 where PARENT_ID is NULL
union all
select p.ROOT_CODE, c.CODE, c.CODE_NAME, c.ID, c.PARENT_ID, p.LVL+1 from t1 c
join p on c.PARENT_ID = p.ID),
t2 as (
select  ROOT_CODE, CODE,CODE_NAME,LVL  from p)
select * from t2
PIVOT
(max(CODE) code, max(CODE_NAME) code_name
for LVL in (1 as "LEV1",2 as "LEV2",3 as "LEV3",4 as "LEV4")
);

 ROOT_CODE  LEV1_CODE LEV1_CODE_  LEV2_CODE LEV2_CODE_  LEV3_CODE LEV3_CODE_  LEV4_CODE LEV4_CODE_
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1 LEVEL 1            11 LEVEL 2           111 LEVEL 3          1111 LEVEL 4   
         2          2 LEVEL 1            21 LEVEL 2
```

The *recursive CTE* calculates the `ROOT_CODE` required for the pivot.
I' leaving as an exercise to fill the not defined levels (with COALESCE) with the previous values as in your example.

In case (as commented) you nedd oner row for each **leave key** a simple solution based on `CONNECT_BY_PATH`is possible.

I'm using again *recursive CTE`calculating the path from *root* to the *current node* and finaly filtering in the result the *leaves* (`ID`that are not`PARENT_ID`)

```
with p ( CODE, CODE_NAME, ID, PARENT_ID, PATH) as (
select   CODE, CODE_NAME, ID, PARENT_ID, to_char(CODE)||'|'||CODE_NAME PATH from t1 where PARENT_ID is NULL
union all
select   c.CODE, c.CODE_NAME, c.ID, c.PARENT_ID, p.PATH ||'|'||to_char(c.CODE)||'|'||c.CODE_NAME from t1 c
join p on c.PARENT_ID = p.ID)
select PATH from p
where ID in (select ID from T1 MINUS  select PARENT_ID from T1)
order by 1;
```

The result holds for any level deepness and is concatenated string with delimiter

```
PATH                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
----------------------------------------------
1|LEVEL 1|11|LEVEL 2|111|LEVEL 3|1111|LEVEL 4
1|LEVEL 1|11|LEVEL 2|112|LEVEL 3
2|LEVEL 1|21|LEVEL 2
3|LEVEL 1
```

Use `substr` `instr` to extract and `coalesce` for the default values.

Comment: This does not work if there are multiple children at a lower depth [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=36c55180e0a2a563bfc456af7e78c0c1)

Answer (score 1):

Solution using a hierarchical query - we record the code and code_name paths, then we break them apart. Level is used to decide whether we populate data from the paths or from the leaf node. The solution assumes the codes and code names do not contain the forward-slash character (if they may, use another separator in the paths - perhaps some control character like `chr(31)`, the unit separator character in ASCII and Unicode).

To break apart the paths, I used `regexp_substr` as it's easier to work with (and, moreover, I assumed all codes and code names are non-null - if they may be null, the solution can be adapted easily). If this proves to be slow, that can be changed to use standard string functions.

```
with
  p (code, code_name, parent_id, lvl, code_pth, code_name_pth) as (
    select  code, code_name, parent_id, level,
            sys_connect_by_path(code, '/') || ',' ,
            sys_connect_by_path(code_name, '/') || ','
    from    t1
    where   connect_by_isleaf = 1
    start   with parent_id is null
    connect by   parent_id = prior id
  )
select case when lvl = 1 then code
            else to_number(regexp_substr(code_pth, '[^/]+', 1, 1)) end as code,
       case when lvl =1 then code_name
            else regexp_substr(code_name_pth, '[^/]+', 1, 1) end as code_name,
       case when lvl <= 2 then code
            else to_number(regexp_substr(code_pth, '[^/]+', 1, 2)) end as code_1,
       case when lvl <= 2 then code_name
            else regexp_substr(code_name_pth, '[^/]+', 1, 2) end as code_name_1,
       case when lvl <= 3 then code 
            else to_number(regexp_substr(code_pth, '[^/]+', 1, 3)) end as code_2,
       case when lvl <= 3 then code_name
            else regexp_substr(code_name_pth, '[^/]+', 1, 3) end as code_name_2,
       code      as code_3,
       code_name as code_name_3
from p;
```